# vibrate iphone/ipod with custom sound

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad

I have my own sound that I want to play while the phone vibrates, the most common thing to do is to do:

```
AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);
```

but this is using the system's sound. Is there a way to use my own sound? What is the format of the sound that I can use?

Comment: Does this actually play a sound? I believe it *only* vibrates

Comment: if you see http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html it does play sound

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check out [AudioServicesPlayAlertSound](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/AudioToolbox/Reference/SystemSoundServicesReference/Reference/reference.html), this will play a custom sound and vibrate if the user has vibration enabled in their sound settings. The proper usage would be something like this...

```
SystemSoundID soundFileObject;

NSURL * soundFileURL= [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource: @"mySoundFile" withExtension: @"aif"];

CFURLRef soundFileURLRef = (CFURLRef) [soundFileURL retain];

AudioServicesCreateSystemSoundID (soundFileURLRef, &soundFileObject);

AudioServicesPlayAlertSound (soundFileObject);
```

The supported file types are .caf, .aif, or .wav according to the above link. Hope that helps!